# Save File & Directory Hierarchy

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have a folder like:

```
Folder
--Sub Folder 1
  --Sub Sub Folder
    --subfile.htm
  --subfile1.txt
  --subfile2.xlx
  --subfile3.doc
  --subfile4.ppt
--Sub Folder 2
--file1.xlsx
--file2.xlsx
```

I want to save this file and directory hierarchy and view it later in a different PC. Is there a software or way which will let me do this?

Comment: If you mean a representation of it, then copy and paste from a dir /s in cmd.  If you mean the actual files, then copy them to a usb stick.  It isn't clear from the question what you want.

Comment: @Paul the `tree` command looks closer to his example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate such a listing in Windows through the command `tree`. To save for future reference, send it to a text file, e.g. `tree /f /a > filename.txt`. The `/f` means display files as well as directories. The `/a` means use ASCII, which can be viewed in Notepad. The default command uses some command prompt extended characters that won't work in most text editors.

The `>` operator means create a new text file and send the command output there. It will overwrite an existing file. Use `>>` to append to an existing file.